# Clash between functions, api not hitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I am using MERN stack and Redux. I have created a function to update a property within a database. I have tested the api on Postman and it works. When i try and run it it seems to clash with another function and i get the error 'TypeError: this.props.subjects.map is not a function' which works prior to the trueVote function being called. Anyone any idea what i am missing here?

Print outs show the action and reducer are being hit but not the api, even though that works on Postman. The function is being called from within the voteHandler

EDIT: The console.log message within the api doesn't print but shows in the terminal window on VS when i refresh my page after the error the function has done what it should and the relevant data has been updated. Is it a case of managing the error? If so how would i do this so it doesn't crash the app?

api

```
// put req for a true vote
subjectRouter.put("subject/true/:_id/:currTrue", (req, res) => {
  console.log("True api hitting");
  Subject.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params._id },
    {
      true: Number(req.params.currTrue) + 1,
    },
    {
      new: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    }
  )
    .then((subject) => res.json(subject))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

action

```
// true vote
export const trueVote = (_id, currTrue) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("trueVote hitting");
  fetch(`/api/subjects/subject/true/${_id}/${currTrue}`, {
    method: "PUT",
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((subject) =>
      dispatch({
        type: TRUE_VOTE,
        subjects: subject,
      })
    );
};
```

reducer

```
case TRUE_VOTE:
      console.log("true reducer hitting");
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.subjects,
      };
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import GoogleSearch from "./GoogleSearch";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchLatestSubjects } from "../../actions/subject";
import { fetchTopicSubjects } from "../../actions/subject";
import { fetchTopicComments } from "../../actions/comment";
import { fetchComments } from "../../actions/comment";
import { rateSubject } from "../../actions/subject";
import { fetchUsers } from "../../actions/authActions";
import { rateUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import { rateComment } from "../../actions/comment";
import { trueVote } from "../../actions/subject";
import { falseVote } from "../../actions/subject";

class Subject extends Component {
  // on loading the subjects and comments
  // are fetched from the database
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLatestSubjects();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // set inital state for subjects
      // description, summary and comments all invisible
      viewDesription: -1,
      viewSummary: -1,
      comments: [],
      topic: "subjects",
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // new subject and comments are added to the top
    // of the arrays
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.subjects.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.comments.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
  }

  clickHandler = (id) => {
    // when a subject title is clicked pass in its id
    const { viewDescription } = this.state;
    this.setState({ comments: [] });
    var temp = [];

    // get the details of the author of the subject and save to state
    const subject = this.props.subjects.find((subject) => subject._id === id);
    const user = this.props.users.find((user) => user._id === subject.author);

    // save comments for subject to temp array
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.props.comments.length; i++) {
      if (this.props.comments[i].subject === id) {
        temp.unshift(this.props.comments[i]);
      }
    }

    console.log(temp);
    // for each comment add a property with the authors name
    temp.forEach((comment) => {
      var commentAuthor = this.props.users.find(
        (user) => user._id === comment.author
      );
      comment.authName = commentAuthor.name;
    });

    // save the subject id to local storage
    // this is done incase a new comment is added
    // then the subject associated  with it can be retrieved
    // and added as a property of that comment
    localStorage.setItem("passedSubject", id);
    localStorage.setItem("passedTopic", subject.topic);
    // add all changes to the state
    this.setState({
      viewDescription: viewDescription === id ? -1 : id,
      comments: temp,
      subAuthor: user.name,
      authRating: user.rating,
      authNoOfVotes: user.noOfVotes,
    });
  };

  // hovering on and off subjects toggles the visibility of the summary
  hoverHandler = (id) => {
    this.setState({ viewSummary: id });
  };
  hoverOffHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ viewSummary: -1 });
  };

  rateHandler = (id, rate, item) => {
    if (item === "subject") {
      // this function rates the subject and the author
      const subject = this.props.subjects.find((subject) => subject._id === id);
      const author = this.props.users.find(
        (user) => user._id === subject.author
      );
      // call the rateSubject and rateUser functions
      this.props.rateSubject(id, rate, subject.noOfVotes, subject.rating);
      this.props.rateUser(author._id, rate, author.noOfVotes, author.rating);
      console.log(author.name);
      alert("Thank you for rating this subject.");
    } else if (item === "comment") {
      const comment = this.props.comments.find((comment) => comment._id === id);
      const author = this.props.users.find(
        (user) => user._id === comment.author
      );
      // call the rateComment and rateUser functions
      this.props.rateComment(id, rate, comment.noOfVotes, comment.rating);
      this.props.rateUser(author._id, rate, author.noOfVotes, author.rating);
      console.log(author.name);
      alert("Thank you for rating this comment.");
    }
  };

  voteHandler = (id, currVote, vote) => {
    if (vote == "True") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.trueVote(id, currVote);
    } else if (vote == "False") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.falseVote(id, currVote);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const subjectItems = this.props.subjects.map((subject) => {
      // if the state equals the id set to visible if not set to invisible
      var view = this.state.viewDescription === subject._id ? "" : "none";
      var hover = this.state.viewSummary === subject._id ? "" : "none";
      var comments = this.state.comments;
      var subjectAuthor = this.state.subAuthor;
      var authRating = this.state.authRating;
      var authNoOfVotes = this.state.authNoOfVotes;
      var className = "";
      if (subject.category === "Education") {
        className = "Education";
      } else if (subject.category === "Environment") {
        className = "Environment";
      } else if (subject.category === "Politics") {
        className = "Politics";
      } else if (subject.category === "Health") {
        className = "Health";
      } else if (subject.category === "Other") {
        className = "Other";
      }

      return (
        <div key={subject._id}>
          <div
            className={className}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.hoverHandler(subject._id)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.hoverOffHandler()}
          >
            <p className="title" onClick={() => this.clickHandler(subject._id)}>
              {subject.title}
            </p>
            <p className="vote" style={{ textAlign: "Right" }}>
              True:{" "}
              {((100 / (subject.true + subject.false)) * subject.true).toFixed(
                1
              )}
              % {" False: "}
              {((100 / (subject.true + subject.false)) * subject.false).toFixed(
                1
              )}
              %
            </p>
            <p className="summary" style={{ display: hover }}>
              {subject.summary}
            </p>
          </div>

          <div className="subjectBody " style={{ display: view }}>
            <div className="leftSubjectBody">
              <div className="subjectAuthor">
                <p className="author">
                  Subject created by: {subjectAuthor} -{" "}
                  {(authRating / authNoOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5 Star user
                  {/* <br /> {subject.date} */}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="subjectDescription">
                <p className="description">{subject.description}</p>
              </div>

              <div className="subjectLinks">Links: {subject.links}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="rightSubjectBody">
              <div className="rate">
                <p> Rate this subject:</p>
                <br />
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 1, "subject")}
                >
                  1
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 2, "subject")}
                >
                  2
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 3, "subject")}
                >
                  3
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 4, "subject")}
                >
                  4
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 5, "subject")}
                >
                  5
                </button>
                <p>
                  Rating: {(subject.rating / subject.noOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="voting">
                <p>
                  Do you think this subject question is true or false based on
                  the evidence provided and your own reseach in the area? <br />
                </p>
                <p>Please vote and leave comments.</p>

                <br />
                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(subject._id, subject.true, "True")
                  }
                >
                  TRUE
                </div>
                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(subject._id, subject.false, "False")
                  }
                >
                  FALSE
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="subjectComments">
              <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Comments:</p>
              {comments.map((comment, i) => {
                return (
                  <div key={i} className="singleComment">
                    <p>
                      {comment.title}
                      <br />
                      {comment.comment}
                      <br />
                      Comment by : {comment.authName} - This user has a rating
                      of {(comment.rating / comment.noOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5
                      STARS
                    </p>
                    <div className="rate">
                      Rate this comment:
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 1, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        1
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 2, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        2
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 3, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        3
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 4, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        4
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 5, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        5
                      </button>
                      <p>
                        Rating:{" "}
                        {(comment.rating / comment.noOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
              <br />
              <a href="/addcomment">
                <div className="buttonAddComment">ADD COMMENT</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div id="Subject">
        <GoogleSearch />
        {subjectItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Subject.propTypes = {
  fetchLatestSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchTopicSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchTopicComments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchComments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rateSubject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rateComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rateUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  trueVote: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  falseVote: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  subjects: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  subjects: state.subjects.items,
  newSubject: state.subjects.item,
  comments: state.comments.items,
  users: state.auth.users,
  newComment: state.comments.item,
});

// export default Subject;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchLatestSubjects,
  fetchTopicSubjects,
  fetchTopicComments,
  fetchComments,
  fetchUsers,
  rateSubject, // rate subject
  rateUser,
  rateComment,
  trueVote,
  falseVote,
})(Subject, Comment);
```

Comment: You are returning `subject` from the true vote, and dispatch it as the `subjects` for `items`, but it's a single `subject`, thus it won't have `map`, probably you want to exchange the previous `subject` in the `state.items` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are returning a single `subject` as part of your reducer action, you presumably want to exchange the existing `subject` with the updated `subject`, so you would need to update your reducer to be:

```
case TRUE_VOTE:
  const index = state.items.subjects.findIndex( subject => action.subjects.id === subject.id );
  return {
    items: [...state.items.slice(0, index), action.subjects, ...state.items.slice( index + 1 )] };
  };
```

To make it a bit more clear, you could of course also change your action to indicate it's only a single subject you are returning

```
// true vote
export const trueVote = (_id, currTrue) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("trueVote hitting");
  fetch(`/api/subjects/subject/true/${_id}/${currTrue}`, {
    method: "PUT",
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((subject) =>
      dispatch({
        type: TRUE_VOTE,
        subject
      })
    );
};
```

Which would then be more clear inside your reducer that you are only expecting 1 subject

Comment: Thank you, i changed the items to item in the reducer which is the single subject, items being the array of them.

Comment: @StephanieMatheson Great, doesn't that mean that `state.items` is no longer in sync with `state.item` until you reload all of your subjects? I think on a previous question of yours I did suggest to split up the components so you would have an easier time managing all the data. I think the bigger the actions become the more work you will have to keep everything in sync

Comment: A new item and updated item go into state.item, state.item is then automatically added back into state.items. Don't ask me how i have done it, I've confused myself with it all but it works so that's all i care about. Thanks again for your help. :)